# How to use CSS flex to make an element occupy 100% of page and center an element within it?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am attempting the following solution described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/22218694/1175080.

> Alternatively, instead of aligning the content via the *container*, flexbox can also center the a **flex item** with an [auto margin](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) *when there is only one flex-item in the flex container* (like the example given in the question above).

Here is my solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style>
  main {
      display: flex;
      height: 100%;
      background: lightgreen;
  }

  section {
      margin: auto;
      background: yellow;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <main>
      <section>Foo</section>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

It does not seem to work. The `main` element does not expand to occupy 100% height of the page. What am I doing wrong? How can this be made to work?

Answer (score 1):

Used `height:100vh`

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

section {
  margin: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <section>Foo</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `html, body` with 100% width & height, Like:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    background: lightgreen;
}

section {
    margin: auto;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <section>Foo</section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The main element will use the space allotted to by it's parents, which in this case are body > html. 
Therefore, set both body and html to have a height of 100% as well and you should be golden.

```
 html, body {
    height: 100%;
 }
```